# Showing that the result of an equation may be a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, perfect-powers

Consider an equation that, for a few select integers $x$, yields a value that is a perfect square. In the case of perfect square quadratics it is easy. For example $(x-2)^2$ will always yield a perfect square value. But what about for an equation like $(x-2)(x-3)$? Or $x^4 -x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1$? Perhaps it yields a perfect square for a few inputs, but is there a way to determine all such inputs?

Comment: In the case of $(x-2)(x-3)=k^2$, since we have a factorization, it follows that any prime that divides $k^2$ must appear twice on the left-hand side as well. Therefore, since $\gcd(x-2,x-3)=1$, both $x-2$ and $x-3$ must be perfect squares, so $x=3$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Théophile I'm gonna be honest with you. I have absolutely no idea what that means. Consider me an absolute baby in number theory. I can comprehend, but only if you explain everything from the grass roots level as I haven't yet started to formally learn number theory.

Comment: @Théophile: $x=2$ is also a solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @Theophile, but I think I can expand a little. Like all numbers, $k$ has a prime decomposition (i.e. $k$ is the product of finitely many primes, e.g. $18=2\times 3 \times 3$). Let's say $p$ prime divides $k$. Then $p$ also divides $k^2$ (twice). Since $(x-2)(x-3)=k^2$, $p$ must also divide $(x-2)(x-3)$ twice. But, $(x-2)$ and $(x-3)$ have no common factors so they are not divisible by $p$, so our only solution can come from $(x-2)$ and $(x-3)$ being squares themselves, i.e. $(x-2)=a^2$, $(x-3)=b^2$ for some $a$, $b$ integers. This only happens when one is zero.

Comment: @Abi but if one term is zero, then the output will also be zero. I want the output to a perfect square and based on that I want to find all inputs for which the output is a perfect square.

Comment: Note that zero is a perfect square: $0=0^2$. (So indeed, I missed $x=2$ in my example above, as @TonyK pointed out.)

Comment: @Théophile But are there no other results that are perfect squares?

Answer (score 1):

We first show that $\gcd(x-2,x-3)=1$, which is to say that $x-2$ and $x-3$ have no common prime factor. Assume to the contrary that $x-2=pa$ and $x-3=pb$ for some prime $p \ge 2$ and integers $a$ and $b$. Now $$1 = (x-2)-(x-3) = pa-pb = p(a-b).$$ This implies $p \mid 1$, contradicting the hypothesis that $p$ is a prime.

Now, by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $$(x-2)(x-3)=k^2$$
implies $x-2=k_1^2$ and $x-3=k_2^2$ for coprime integers $k_1$ and $k_2$, such that $k=k_1k_2$. But the only two consecutive square integers are $0$ and $1$. Hence $x-2=1$ and $x-3=0$ is the only solution where $x-2$ is positive. The second solution comes through the power of zero to absorb everything: $x-2=0$ and $x-3=-1$ means $(x-2)(x-3)=0\cdot(-1)=0$, and since $0=0^2$ is a square, it counts.